# VBA: how to avoid copying table headers from multiple sheets?

Tags: vba

Trying to combine multiple excel sheets is there a way to modify the below so that it does not copy table headers from the other sheets into a sheet called "Combined"?

```
Sub Combine()
'UpdatebyExtendoffice
Dim J As Integer
On Error Resume Next
Sheets(1).Select
Worksheets.Add
Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"
Sheets(2).Activate
Range("A1").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")
For J = 2 To Sheets.Count
Sheets(J).Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Does `Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select` not do what you are asking?

Comment: I need it to skip A2 as well, think I got it if I modify to -2 that should work.

Comment: Your "Offset" is doing the skipping so you'll want to offset by 2 rows AND Resize by `-2` rows. So `Selection.Offset(2, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 2).Select` will do the job.

Comment: It worked, but only for the first sheet the others are still copying A2 to the combined sheet.

Comment: I believe you, but it also doesn't make any sense. I'm going to do a quick rewrite to get rid of your superfluous `.Activate` and `.Select` stuff. Perhaps it will clear up whatever bug is being introduced that it's only working for the one sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try the next updated code, please:

```
Sub CombineSheets()
 Dim J As Long, sh As Worksheet

 Worksheets.Add Before:=Sheets(1)
 Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"
 Sheets(2).Range("A1").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")

 For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If sh.Name <> Sheets(1).Name Then
        sh.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(2).Resize(sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row - 1).Copy _
                                                                             Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A" & sh.rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
    End If
 Next
End Sub
```

Selecting, activating only consume Excel resources and make the code slower...

Comment: Still the same issue of it not skipping A2. :(

Comment: @patpat91 But, shouldn't it skip only the first row (table headers, as you say...)? Are there headers on the second row? Can you edit the question and show us how such a sheet to be copied looks?

Comment: @patpat91 with this version of the code you can do `sh.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(2).Resize(sh.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows - 2).Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A" & sh.rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)` to skip the first two rows. @FaneDuru may have a cleaner way to do that resize though.

Comment: @JNevill He can, but why to do it? This will only skip the **last row**. Didn't it want to skip only the first row? He headers, as he say in the question title...

Comment: @FaneDuru I too was confused by the title. Really OP is wanting to not only skip the first line (which they were already doing with that `Offset().Resize()` stuff), but also the second line, which wasn't detailed well in the question (came out in the commentS).

Comment: @patpat91 So, try the updated code. It will also skip the second row...

Comment: @JNevill He only said that in his comment. He requested to skip the headers... I updated the code in order to also skip the second row... But I am not sure that he knows very well what he wants, no offence for him.

Answer (score 0):

Quick rewrite and introducing some variables to hold the new sheet and copy range which should help for debugging.

This also incorporates the "skip two header rows" requirement:

```
Sub Combine()
    Dim J As Integer       
    
    'Set the newly added sheet to a variable so we can reference.
    Dim CombineSheet as Worksheet
    Set CombineSheet = Worksheets.Add
    CombineSheet.Name = "Combined"
    
    'Assume you are copying the header here. It's a 
    '   little risky hoping that Sheets(2) is going 
    '   to be the one you want.
    'Furthermore, getting rid of select/activate 
    '   stuff. Instead directly say which sheet and 
    '   range you want to copy and its destination.
    Sheets(2).Range("A1").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=CombineSheet.Range("A1")
    
    'Introducing a new variable to hold the range that will be copied
    Dim copyRange as Range
    For J = 2 To Sheets.Count

        'Cutting out the activates and selects here
        Set copyRange = Sheets(J).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        
        'Offset it and resize skipping 2 header rows and resizing the whole
        '   range to be 2 rows smaller (the 2 rows we just skipped)
        copyRange = copyRange.Offset(2).Resize(copyRange.Rows.Count - 2)

        'Copy/Paste
        copyRange.Copy Destination:=CombineSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp)       
       
    Next
End Sub
```

The biggest change here, besides the removal of the `.Select` and `.Activate` is just offsetting by 2 rows and then resizing that range by `-2` rows to accommodate that offset.

Comment: Thank you! Says Object variable or with block variable not set.

Comment: Now I wish I had my windows computer to debug. It's been a while since I wrote VBA. Which line is it throwing the error on (highlighted when you hit the "Debug" button.

Comment: Its this line copyRange = Sheets(J).Range("A1").CurrentRegion. I am very new to VBA, just trying to make my life at work easier. :)

Comment: Oh. Throw the word `Set` in front of that line and give it another shot. I updated the code to reflect that.